# How to obtain string not longer than certain length in R

Tags: string, r

I have a vector of strings that looks like this

```
x <- c("WDNTO","WDRN","WDSAX","WECAX","WEN","WEDTO")
```

What I want to do is to extract only strings not longer than 4 characters,
resulting in

```
  WDNT,WDRN,WDSA,WECA,WEN,WEDT
```

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
substr(x,1,4)
?substr
```

My first answer on SO!

Comment: ...and someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `substr`, eg

```
substr(x, 1, 4)
```